# Conditionally run check in express-validator

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, express-validator

I am trying to conditionally run check in express validator, the functional part of the validator can easily be handled because I am passing in req but the check part won't conditionally run. Please help

I've tried turning the check part to a function and it is not working. This is what I want to achieve but the tenary fails

```
const onewayCheck = body('tripType').equals('one-way') ? [
  body('currentOfficeLocation')
    .exists({ checkFalsy: true })
    .withMessage('currentOfficeLocation Current Office Location is required')
    .isInt()
    .withMessage('currentOfficeLocation Current Office Location must be an integer'),
  body('destination')
    .exists({ checkFalsy: true })
    .withMessage('destination Destination is required')
    .isInt()
    .withMessage('destination Destination must be an integer'),
  body('departureDate')
    .exists({ checkFalsy: true })
    .withMessage('departureDate Departure date is required'),
  body('travelreasons')
    .exists({ checkFalsy: true })
    .withMessage('travelReasons Travel Reasons is required')
    .isString()
    .withMessage('travelReasons Travel Reasons should be strings'),
  body('accommodation')
    .exists({ checkFalsy: true })
    .withMessage('accommodation Accommodation is required')
    .isInt()
    .withMessage('accommodation Accommodation must be an integer'),
] : [];
```

I want to ensure the check woks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it by using a middleware in the route as follows

```
router
  .post('/request', validate(onewayCheck(), 'one-way'),
    onewayValidateInput,
    validate(multicityCheck(), 'Multi-city'), multicityValidateInput, tripRequest)
```

The validate function checks for the type of request

```
const validate = (validations, tripType) => async (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.body.tripType === tripType) {
    await Promise.all(validations.map(validation => validation.run(req)));
  }
  return next();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to run the check during validation. Instead you can check it inside your controller.
For example, assuming you check for validation errors in your controller like this

```
const errors = validationResult(req);
if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    return res.status(422).json({ errors: errors.array() });
}
```

You can run your check about returning the errors or not this way

```
if (req.body.tripType === 'one-way') {
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        return res.status(422).json({ errors: errors.array() });
    }
}
```

That way the validation logic will run in any case, but you will return validation errors only if `tripType` has value `one-way`.

Comment: The problem is I've got several other validations on the route. I just want to  check for a condition and move over to the next validation. I've handled the error messages returned to the user but when once it comes to the next validation the previous checks are returned alongside

Answer (score 0):

Someone helped me with the solution
/// route.js

```
const router = express.Router();

const validate = (validations, tripType) => {
  return async (req, res, next) => {
    if (req.body.tripType === tripType) {
      await Promise.all(validations.map(validation => validation.run(req)));
    }
    return next();
  };
};

router.post('/request', authenticate, validateRequestType, validate(onewayCheck(), 'one-way'),
  onewayValidateInput, multicityCheck, multicityValidateInput, tripRequest);

export default router;

///in the validation file
const onewayCheck = () => [
  body('currentOfficeLocation')
    .exists({ checkFalsy: true })
    .withMessage('currentOfficeLocation Current Office Location is required')
    .isInt()
    .withMessage('currentOfficeLocation Current Office Location must be an integer'),
  body('destination')
    .exists({ checkFalsy: true })
    .withMessage('destination Destination is required')
    .isInt()
    .withMessage('destination Destination must be an integer'),
  body('departureDate')
    .exists({ checkFalsy: true })
    .withMessage('departureDate Departure date is required'),
  body('travelreasons')
    .exists({ checkFalsy: true })
    .withMessage('travelReasons Travel Reasons is required')
    .isString()
    .withMessage('travelReasons Travel Reasons should be strings'),
  body('accommodation')
    .exists({ checkFalsy: true })
    .withMessage('accommodation Accommodation is required')
    .isInt()
    .withMessage('accommodation Accommodation must be an integer'),
];
```